# Problema ao carregar imagem no HTML (Performance)

Tags: html, html5, desempenho, imagem, otimização

Enquanto é feito o download e execução do script todo o processo de parser do DOM é bloqueado, isso impede a renderização do resto da página. E isso se aplicada a cada tag de script da página.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Um jeito** que encontrei de "contornar" esse problema foi colocar todos os JavaScripts no rodapé do site ( no final do body ) e não mais dentro da tag head como vinha fazendo, dessa forma eles serão os últimos a serem baixados e não vão bloquear o carregamento da página é até uma técnica já bem conhecida.

**Porém** o problema é que mesmo usando esse artifício eu fico com o problema de renderização, veja que na imagem que o arquivo teste.bmp ( é um exemplo viu, 11mb na imagem é só para demonstrar o problema) essa imagem só começa a ser carregada depois do DOM ser carregado (linha vertical), ela fica "aguardando" tudo ser carregado para somente então fazer o refresh(renderização).

**Pergunta:** Existe alguma forma de renderizar as imagens em paralelo(em relação aos scripts) tudo junto, **sem esperar** o DOM carregar tudo.

Comment: A imagem já está no HTML ou é inserida por um script?

Comment: Esta no HTML mesmo, se fosse carregada por um script eu até me conformaria, mas se esta ali tudo junto, porque será que isso não roda de forma concorrente junto com os scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tentou realizar o carregamento assíncrono dos arquivos JS? Caso não você pode utilizar uma ferramenta chamada LABjs. Você referência somente ela no antes do fechamento do body e carrega desse forma seus scripts.

//Carrega os scripts em paralelo, porém na ordem que foi passado

```
$LAB.script('script1.js').wait()
    .script('script2.js').wait()
    .script('script3.js');
```

//Caso algum script não tenha dependência com os anteriores, pode carregar ele em paralelo separadamente.

```
$LAB.script('script4.js');
```

O HTML5 suporta o atributo async na tag do script, porém acredito que ainda tenha incompatibilidade com alguns navegadores.

Comment: Então Rafael, os script estão carregando em paralelo, o problema são as imagens que só començam a ser carregadas depois que DOM termina, mas vou tentar usando esse LABjs e depois posto o resultado

Comment: desculpe a demora, é que não estava sobrando tempo para fazer os testes, segui a sua dica ai e resolveu o problema obrigado